# Can we place webpage functionality URL in the Facebook Web Games Page URL.?

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps, facebook-app-center

I am trying to create a functionality and load on Facebook, the page will be load as "apps.facebook.com/appname". Can we use "Facebook Web Games" to load our application on Facebook. 
In earlier days i have placed the webpage URL in the Facebook Canvas URL. But this feature doesn't exist on Facebook.
Anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can we use "Facebook Web Games" to load our application on Facebook.

Facebook Web Games *is* what used to be called the Canvas platform.

Facebook just renamed it, after they decided to use the “Canvas” name for their new advertising format.

So yes, you just put the URL of the page you want to display under `apps.facebook.com/appname` in the Facebook Web Games settings.

(This is not limited to games, despite the naming. If you want to show other content that way, that is fine as well.)